# Destination host unreachable pinging from vmware guest to the host

Tags: vmware, ping, host, ehostunreach

I am running a VMWare  VM on a win10home laptop. Laptop has its own ethernet rj45 plug and is connected to other PCs in a net.
VM is  win10pro. I assigned the Bridged connection type to the network connection in the VM network adapter.
I assigned compatible IP address to host and guest (example 192.168.100.xxx and 192.168.100.yyy). Subnet mask is ever 255.255.255.0
They cannot ping each other from the host to the guest and from the guest to the host.
If I ping from example the guest then message is:
"Reply from 192.168.100.yyy: Destination host unreachable (4 times)
Statistic for 192.168.100.xxx ; transmitted = 4, received = 4, lost = 0 (0%)".
The same in the viceversa.

BUT if from the host I ping other nodes in the network, then ping is working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Vmware-
Virtual Network Adapter-
VmNet0-
VmNet Information-
Bridge to...